SQL (Hive) fill in missing dates with values from last non empty day
I have a table with 5 columns: date - date of temperature measurement, process_id - identifier of the process for which the temperature is measured, batch_id - identifier of the upload batch, code - upload code, value - temperature value for the process.
hive table
Some dates are missed. It may be the case that several days in a row have been missed.
I need to fill in the missing dates so that each date has a fixed set of rows (all unique combinations of process_id, batch_id, code). For example, for the date 15.01.2021, the following combinnations of process_id, batch_id, code are present (orange color):
records of 2021-01-15
On the date 16.01.2021, only the following process_id values are present:
records of 2021-01-16
In the example above missing values with process_id=18 and process_id=19 should be added:
fillin on 2021-01-16
After adding records by missing processes, I need to fill in the missed values in columns
process_id, batch_id, code, value with the last not null value on previous date by combination process_id, batch_id, code. See the picture above.
Also there may be situations where a date is missing. In the example above, measurements for the date 17.01.2021 are missing.
In this case, missing records for the date 17.01.2021 should be added. A total of 5 records will be added (process_id: 15, 16, 17, 18, 19).
enter image description here
After adding the records for the missing date, the last non-null temperature value for each process from the previous date should be propagated.
My current query:
with cvc as (
    select t.code,
           t.process_id,
           d.next_date,
           t.batch_id
    from (select date_add(from_date, i) as next_date
                 from ( select min(date) as from_date,
                               max(date) as  to_date
                        from measures
                        where year(date)=2021 and month(date)>=1
                        ) p
            lateral view posexplode(split(space(datediff(p.to_date, p.from_date)))) pe as i, x
         ) d 
    cross join (
        select distinct code,
                        process_id,
                       batch_id
        from measures
        where year(date)=2021 and month(date)>=1
    )  c              
    left join (
        select   code,
                 process_id,
                 date,
                 batch_id
        from    measures
        where year(date)=2021 and month(date)>=1
    )   t 
    on t.code=c.code
    and t.process_id=c.process_id
    and t.date=d.next_date
    and t.batch_id=c.batch_id
)
select 
      next_date,
      coalesce(code, last_value(code, true) 
      over(partition by code, process_id, order by next_date 
      rows between unbounded preceding and current row)) as code,
       
      ... 
        ...
     coalesce(process_id, last_value(process_id, true) 
     over(partition by code, process_id, order by next_date 
     rows between unbounded preceding and current row)) as process_id
from cvc
order by
next_date,
code,
process_id,
batch_id

The query presented above correctly fills in the majority of values. However, in some cases, there are duplicates for the same date. For example, for process_id=19 on 2021-01-17, there are two entries with different values (highlighted in red).
enter image description here
The desired output:
enter image description here
This needs to be done in Hive.
Please, help

BTW: Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?, and Welcome to Stackoverflow!  Please read: How to ask, especially the "Search, and research" part..
